# fread and textareas - textarea in output closes tag

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a bit of code for my CMS that enables the user (they requested this!) to edit ANY page on the server. They request the page and are sent to the edit page. Here they can edit name, content and save it.

For the content I am using a textarea to output the file content so they can edit. Like so;

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" rows="30" cols="180">
<?php
    $file = fopen($_POST['file'],"r");
    echo fread($file,filesize($_POST['file']));
    fclose($file);
?>
</textarea>
```

However if I edit a page that contains a textarea, the edit page closes the tag and the rest of the page that should be echo'd in the textarea leaks out.

Any ideas? I'm guessing I need to strip tags or something?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Can you give an example of `leaks out`? Plus a bit more code would help.

Comment: Lets say the file contains 

    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <textarea> Text </textarea>
    </body>
    </html>

the text area tags that are echo'd Inside the text area value end up closing the tag. This has been fixed with the post below and htmlentities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will afford to suggest `file_get_contents()` over what you're doing, so the code will go as

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" rows="30" cols="180">
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents($_POST['file']);
    echo htmlentities($file);
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to use htmlentities rather than html_entities but close enough ;) Thanks again!

Comment: @Nicholas-c I wrote this by memory, it's totally possible it had cheated on me `:D`. Corrected the naswer! `:P`